# Overriding the operator= in C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

My task is to implement a method that overrides the = operator. I have something written, but honestly I have no idea what I'm doing. Can someone explain what the point of doing this overriding is (not in general, I understand that, but just in this case, Im a bit confused)? What is my method supposed to accomplish? Where does my logic fail in my current code?

```
scene.cpp:70: error: no match for ‘operator=’ in ‘*(((Image*)(((long unsigned int)i) * 80ul)) + newArray) = *(((Scene*)this)->Scene::images + ((Image**)(((long unsigned int)i) * 8ul)))’
```

Comment: wow, this is evilness in action :)

Comment: its got lots of bad things going on....

Comment: @Keith: It's not correct, sure, but the "badness" is being highly over-exaggerated. They're called mistakes, we all make them, it doesn't mean the worlds ending. Chill.

Comment: I would be surprised if this even compiles. Does it?

Comment: Use the [copy-and-swap idiom](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom), it's simple and effective. It requires you have a working copy-constructor, if you need help with that just ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your (inner) code does in English:

```
//allocate new memory and copy
images = new Image*[source.maximum];
```

This sets `images` to a newly allocated array of `source.maximum` uninitialized `Image` pointers.  Whatever `images` was pointing to is lost.

```
    Scene(source);
```

This creates a new temporary `Scene` object and then throws it away.  it does not "re-call" the constructor on `this`.

```
    //deallocate old memory
    delete *source;
```

This, if it worked, would dereference `source` (which is a `const Scene&`, so this only works if `T* Scene::operator *(void)` is defined, where `T` is some type) and delete the pointed-to `T` object.

```
    //assign
    source=images;
```

This tries to copy `images` over `source`, which shouldn't happen since `source` is `const`.  Once created, a reference cannot be changed to reference a different object.

```
    this->maximum=images.maximum;
```

This doesn't work. `images` is a `Image**` which does not have a `maximum` field. Also, the `this->` is redundant.

**UPDATE:** Regarding then new version:

First, you don't need to say `this->` everywhere.

```
for (int i=0;i<source.maximum;i++)
    this->images[i]=source->images[i];
```

The problem here is that `source` is a reference, not a pointer, so you should be using `source.images[i]` instead of `source->images[i]`.

Assuming this is fixed, now the issue is that the image objects are pointed to by both the current object as well as `source`.  If either object releases memory (`delete images[i]; images[i] = 0;` or similar), then the pointer in the other object becomes invalid. *If images are never deleted,* then this code is fine.

If, however, you want this object to have its own copies of the images, then you need to do more work:

```
if(this != &source)
{
    // Delete old images.
    for(int i = 0; i < maximum; i++)
        delete images[i];
    delete[] images;

    // Copy new images.
    maximum = source.maximum;
    images = new Image*[maximum];
    for(int i = 0; i < maximum; i++)
        images[i] = new Image(*(source.images[i]));
}
```

This assumes you have a copy constructor for `Image` (`Image::Image(const Image&);`).

Finally, `Scene` should have a copy constructor that works similarly to this one, except it doesn't need to delete old stuff.  If you *don't* make copies of images, use:

```
Scene::Scene(const Scene& original): maximum(original.maximum)
{
    images = new Image*[maximum];
    for(size_t i = 0; i < maximum; i++)
        images[i] = source.images[i];
}
```

If you *do* make copies of images, use:

```
Scene::Scene(const Scene& original): maximum(original.maximum)
{
    images = new Image*[maximum];
    for(size_t i = 0; i < maximum; i++)
        images[i] = new Image(*(source.images[i]));
}
```

In both cases, don't forget to add `Scene(const Scene& original);` to the class definition.

Answer (score 1):

It is very tricky to implement a copy constructor or assignment operator in a class that manages memory, and keep your code exception safe.  Exception safety means ensuring that if an exception is thrown at any point in your program, that your manually managed memory is still cleaned up correctly.  A few idioms have cropped up to help with this:

- [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization)

RAII's basic tenant is that if you have to manage memory (which much more often lately, you don't), wrap the memory handling in an object that allocates only one piece of memory on construction, and deallocates that memory on destruction.

- [Copy-and-Swap](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Copy-and-swap)

Copy and swap is specific guidance for implementing a non-trivial assignment operator when you have to deal with memory allocation.  This is the exact scenario you are trying to solve.

I recommend you read about both quite a bit before continuing to try to write code that manages memory, or you'll probably tear your hair out trying to squash all your bugs.

An alternative to implementing idioms yourself is to rely on code like `std::vector` and `tr1::shared_ptr` to do your memory management for you.  Plenty of people who know C++ and memory management oddities inside-out use both of those on a regular basis.  You can very often get away with just those.

Answer (score 0):

Overriding an operater is like overloading a function now; you can do a copy via the = op.

```
Scene A;
Scene B;

A.do_things();
B = A;
```

If you didn't overload the = operator; B=A would have made B a pointer to the same object as A (since class instance variables in C are pointers).

Comment: See Keith's answer...  It looks fishy ;-).  Your releasing memory in one instance of an object that belongs to another's.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you are wanting it to do.  But its got lots of faults

Typically, operator= would take a copy of the original without making any changes to the original.

This looks like you are wanting to transfer ownership of your images from one object to another.

delete *source is just DANGEROUS as it isn't / shouldn't be the owner.  source could easily be a stack variable.

source != images   so assigning images to source is just going to kill things

storing the images in a vector would handle allocating memory and also copying of all the images for you.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things wrong with your code.

1. Do not `delete source`, you pass it in as a reference to const, so leave it alone!
2. Do not alter source. It is const so you can't.
3. Do no allocate new memory to `this->images` whithout a `delete[] images` first.
4. You need to understand the difference between references and pointers first.
5. You need to understand what `const` is.
6. You cannot assign `images` to `source` for a variety of reasons. One being that you shouldn't (can't) assign to `source`. Another is that, unless a `Scene` is an `Image`, you cannot go assigning an `Image` to a `Scene` pointer.

Answer (score 0):

There's a canonical solution to implementing a non-trivial assignment operator:

```
Scene const & Scene::operator=(Scene s) { swap(s); return *this; }
void Scene::swap(Scene & s) /* nothrow */ {
    Image *temp_images = images; images = s.images; s.images = temp_images;
    int temp_maximum = maximum; maximum = s.maximum; s.maximum = temp_maximum;
}
```

This is completely exception-safe, as it relies on the copy-constructor to create a temporary copy of the source before swapping it in (using a no-throw swap) to replace the target. If any part of the copy goes awry, both source and target will remain as before.

The only thing it doesn't do is optimise self-assignment. It does, however, work correctly in the presence of self-assignment, and I don't generally bother optimising something that shouldn't happen (and which rarely does, in practice).

Another option is to use a more conventional parameter type:

```
Scene const & Scene::operator=(Scene const & s) {
    Scene temp(s);
    swap(temp);
    return *this;
}
```

However, apart from being more wordy, this version is potentially less efficient, since it guarantees that a copy is made, whereas the pass-by-value version may elide the copy if the parameter passed to s is an rvalue.

Comment: Why not use `std::swap` in the implementation of `swap`? For what it's worth, this idiom is called [copy-and-swap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom), and the rationale behind various things is given in that link.

Comment: @GMan: I like to avoid including more header files than I need. I would use `std::swap` if I had to swap a non-trivial member, like a `std::vector`.

Comment: except images now points to the same allocated memory as "s"  which will likelydeallocate the memory on its destructor (whenever that happens) likely leaving the object pointing at garbase

Comment: @Marcelo: That's an absolutely terrible reason. Your code is noisy, messy, and error-prone, all because you don't want to include the free-to-include `<utility>`? It costs nothing to include it. @Keith: The point is to leverage a *working* copy-constructor.

Comment: @Marcelo is there anyway to implement your code above without changing the original function parameters?

Comment: @GMan: Nothing costs nothing. The code is correct. How you derive "error-prone" from correct code is a little beyond me. Maybe I'm just too much of a crusty old fart, but I've seen enough swaps to recognise one on sight, so "noisy" and "messy" simply don't ring true for me.

Comment: @Keith: No it won't. Because `s` is passed by value, the copy constructor has already made an isolated copy of the `Image *`.

Comment: @iRobot: Apart from numerous glitches in your current code, it is fundamentally the wrong way to go about it. Use copy-and-swap, as I've describe it above (and feel free to use `std::swap` instead of my crufty old hand-crafted swap).

Comment: @Marcello what is this line doing: Scene temp(s); ?

Comment: @iRobot: It constructs a temporary copy of the `Scene` from `s`.

Comment: @iRobot: Just to be clear on what I'm advising. All the copying code should go into your copy constructor, which I presume you've already written. Assuming `images` and `maximum` are the only member variables, the code I presented (either version) will implement assignment safely.

Comment: @Marcelo: "Nothing" is a word, as is "cost", and those can be results from arbitrary models we might create, don't be needlessly stupefied. What cost model are you working with where including a standard header costs something? It's error-prone to re-write something over and over, as in "it's possible an error will occur". It's not possible for such a thing to happen if you use `std::swap`, because the working functionality is *re-used*, not reimplemented. It's noisy and messy because you've manually inlined a call to an existing function, you wouldn't do that anywhere else would you?

Comment: @Gman: Your opening sentence leaves me stumped, I'm afraid. It seems like you're explaining something to someone you think is a bit simple, but I'll be the optimist and assume that I've completely misread you. FWIW, I partly agree with you. It is largely just an old habit of mine. I suppose my threshold for reuse lies at a different level to yours. `std::swap` is so ridiculously simple, that I often find it quicker to just type the extra few characters right where I am in the code than to navigate my way to the top, add a #include, and then find my way back to the line of code I was at.